# Matlab - With ... End structure

Tags: matlab

Does Matlab have a kind of with...end command? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.80).aspx

I have a variable in my workspace which contains a lot of nested data. Now I don't want to have to type this all the time:

```
Root.ChildLevel1.A = Root.ChildLevel1.B + Root.ChildLevel1.C
```

But rather something like:

```
with Root.ChildLevel1
  A = B + C
end
```

is this possible?

Comment: It's indeed annoying to type, and there's no way to do this what you want as @Shai points out. However, when you create the structure `Root` with all fields in the command window, Tab-expansion will work in your code.

Comment: Nice question, it is not a solution but you may be able to avoid the problem in most cases by not nesting too deep and either adding dimensions to your variables or using underscores here and there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of such functionality in Matlab.
What you can do is

```
cur = Root.ChildLevel1;
cur.A = cur.B + cur.C;
```

**Edit:**
According to comment by @Nick, if `Root.ChildLevel1` is **not** [subclass of `handle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.html),
then one should add the following line:

```
Root.ChildLevel1 = cur;
```

I would also recommend to

```
clear cur;
```

at the end.

Comment: to change the property A of this object, Root.ChildLevel1 needs to be a subclass of handle.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I would not recommend using this function very often, but I once tried a FEX contribution that allows you to unpack structs.

Of course this will still require you to update the struct after you have done the calculations so I only use it for subfunctions that mainly use the struct as input.

I am not sure, but I think this is the one I tried:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26216-structure-fields-to-variables